# Cell Update using App.Match - Faster than App.VLookup?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search for a key value of "PR Data" looking in "PR Data Windchill".  Once found, I'd like to copy the 6th cell to the right of found in "PR Data Windchill" and paste back to the original key in the 6th cell to the right in "PR Data".

I've tried using Application.VLookup and, although it worked, it was slow.  I'm working with data ranges that are 50,000-100,000 items long.

```
Function Update()

Dim Master As Worksheet
Dim Slave As Worksheet
Dim lrS As Long
Dim i As Long, m, SLookup As Range

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data Windchill")
Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data")

Set SLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data Windchill").Columns(1)

lrS = Slave.Cells(Slave.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Slave
    For i = 7 To lrS
        Select Case .Range("G" & i)
        Case Is = "" '"Open", "Under Review", "Accepted"
        m = Application.Match(.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, SLookup, 0)
        .Rows(i).Cells(1).Offset(0, 6).Copy Slave.Rows(i).Cells(1).Offset(0, 6)
        End Select
    Next i
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox ("Status Update Complete")

End Function
```

Comment: Use dictionaries and arrays. It will take seconds to do the job.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246138/how-do-i-speed-up-a-double-for-loop-with-if-in-the-inner-loop-in-vba/56246302#56246302) a question similar to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no gaps in Column A on either sheet and the first row of data is Row 1...

```
Function Update()

Dim Master As Worksheet
Dim Slave As Worksheet

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data Windchill")
Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data")

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim rc As Long
rc = 1
Do Until Master.Cells(rc, 1) = ""
    If Not dict.Exists(Master.Cells(rc, 1).Value) Then dict.Add Master.Cells(rc, 1).Value, Master.Cells(rc, 7).Value
    rc = rc + 1
Loop

rc = 7 'changed from 1
Do Until Slave.Cells(rc, 1) = ""
    If Slave.Cells(rc, 7).Text = "" Then
        If dict.Exists(Slave.Cells(rc, 1).Value) Then Slave.Cells(rc, 7) = dict(Slave.Cells(rc, 1).Value)
    End If
    rc = rc + 1
Loop

MsgBox ("Status Update Complete")

End Function
```

Comment: There are no gaps in key cells...  Column A is the same on both sheets.  Data in "PR Data Windchill" starts on row 2, but data on "PR Data" starts on row 7.

Comment: Just needed to change the second 'rc' initialisation as above.
As Damien correctly called out, Dictionaries are much faster when doing things like this.

Comment: Dictionaries along with arrays, you are still working on the sheet. Working the sheet taxes the execution time, if you get everything into arrays the execution will be even faster.

Comment: So, my original code only looked at empty cells (Case Is = ""), but I now want to make it work on (Case Is = "Open", "Under Review", "Accepted").  Do I change the Do Until ... = "" to my other cases?

Comment: The part to change is `Slave.Cells(rc, 7).Text = ""`.  So you would have  `If Slave.Cells(rc, 7).Text = "" or Slave.Cells(rc, 7).Text = "Open" or ... Then`.  There are a few ways to do this but this is the simplest